# PyCharm/IntelliJ enable package dependency inspection

Tags: python, python-2.7, intellij-idea, pycharm, intellij-14

I was getting this warning automatically `Package requirements ....`

[image]

& things were working fine when I was clicking on the `Install requirements`

RECENTLY, I clicked on `Ignore requirements` by mistake. And this automatic check does NOT happen anymore. I am having a hard time trying to figure where I should enable it on PyCharm.

I am currently doing it with `pip` on terminal. Any help here to enable this will be nice.

Looking forward to the comments/answer-help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto `File > Settings > Tools > Python Integrated Tools`

set your requirements file with the `Package requirements file:` input box.
[image: PyCharm Integrated Tools settings dialog]

now navigate to `Editor > Inspections` on the search box, search for requirements, check the checkbox next to Package requirements.

[image: package requirements inspection pycharm]

---

> To manage dependencies with PyCharm, you can go to `settings > project > project interpreter`, select your interpreter from the drop down menu

[image: PyCharm settings select interpreter]

click on the green `+` button to open the package list/install dialog. select the version from the specify version drop down and click `install package`.
[image: PyCharm install packages.]